# ngmodel on ngoptions inside ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

```
<p><b>Client Name</b></p>
<div ng-repeat="client in clientList">
  <b>{{client.name}}</b>
  <select value="Please select bot from list" ng-model='???' ng-options="b as b.name for b in listOfBots" |>
  </select>
</div>
<button ng-click="(getBotSelection())">Select Bots</button>
```

I'm not finding any articles pertaining to this particular implementation. clientList is a list coming from an excel file telling me to update clients. I need to run a bot for that client so I'm setting ng-options to bot.name in listOfBots.

The issue with the articles I'm finding is that they typically aren't iterating over two separate collections in the examples. I'm having a hard time with this one, please help.

list of bots looks like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < listOfBotsArr.length; i++) {
      listOfBotsObj.push({
        name: listOfBotsArr[i]
      });
      $scope.$apply();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-show="showBotList">
  <p>You must select which bots to run manually</p>
  <p><b>Client Name</b></p>
  <div ng-repeat="client in clientList">


    <b>{{client.name}}</b>
    <select value="Please select bot from list" ng-model="bot" ng-options="b as b.name for b in listOfBots" ng-change="getSelectedBot(this.bot.name)" |>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="">Select Bots</button>
</div>
```

this was my solution. Passing "this" with ng-change and logging it, showed me the object I was returning, and it had a property bot.name, so there we have it.